# django-rq configuration and installation in apps.py

Tags: python, django, django-rq

I use [`django-rq`](https://github.com/rq/django-rq) in my Django application. Currently, I install `django-rq` with pip, then add the following content to `mysite/settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += 'django_rq'

RQ_QUEUES = {
    'default': {
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 6379,
        'DB': 0,
        'DEFAULT-TIMEOUT': 360,
    }
}
```

This works well, but I want to distribute my application with an installation process as simple as possible. Is there a way to move the previous content of `settings.py` to `my-app/apps.py` or any other file distributed with my application?

Something like

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        settings.INSTALLED_APPS += 'django_rq'
        settings.RQ_QUEUES = {
            'default': {
                'HOST': 'localhost',
                'PORT': 6379,
                'DB': 0,
                'DEFAULT-TIMEOUT': 360,
            }
        }
```

This obviously won't work and is not recommended by the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime), but you get the idea.

Comment: So, if you want to have multiple settings for different environments, that you can create a settings folder and put a __init__.py in that folder. Make multiple setting files like dev1.py, dev2.py and based on the environment import that file in the __init__.py.

Comment: Thanks for the message, but I'm afraid this does not answer my question. What should I put in the `dev1.py` to add `django_rq` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` and configure the queues?

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS += 'django_rq'
        settings.RQ_QUEUES = {
            'default': {
                'HOST': 'localhost',
                'PORT': 6379,
                'DB': 0,
                'DEFAULT-TIMEOUT': 360,
            }
        }`

Comment: Does it mean the last snippet of my question actually works? It sounds strange, knowing that an imported `django.conf.settings` is a LazySettings, and is probably read-only. EDIT: I just tried, and I get an `ImproperlyConfigured` exception. It definitely does not work.